# Umbraco cannot AddModelError during HttpPost in SurfaceController

Tags: c#, validation, model, umbraco, umbraco7

When validating a model in an Umbraco `SurfaceController` during a form post back I'm unable to use `ModelState.AddModelError` to add validation error messages for providing feedback to the user. Any ideas why?

I can use `ModelState.AddModelError` in `[ChildActionOnly]` rendering method without issue.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult VerifyEmail(VerifyEmailModel model)
{
    // This DOES work
    ModelState.AddModelError("SomeProperty", "Some error message to display.");

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult VerifyEmailSubmit(VerifyEmailModel model)
{
    // This DOESN'T work
    ModelState.AddModelError("SomeProperty", "Some error message to display.");

    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

I guess I can try to code up custom a `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` but the validation I need to do requires looking up data based on other model properties so starts to get a bit complex.

Comment: I've cross posted this to the Umbraco forums in case Umbraco developers are more active there instead of Stack Overflow - https://our.umbraco.org/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/76443-cannot-addmodelerror-during-httppost-in-surfacecontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to a coding a custom `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` to work around the issue:

```
public class VerificationCodeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string code = (string)value;
        Guid userId = Guid.Empty;

        PropertyInfo userIdProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("UserId");
        if (userIdProperty != null)
            userId = (Guid)userIdProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        // See if we're confirming email via link
        if (userId == Guid.Empty)
            userId = MyProject.Identity.Client.GetUser().Id;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code) && !MyProject.Identity.Client.VerifyUserEmail(userId, code))
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid email verification code.");

        return null; // Default for empty string
    }
}
```

However, this work around may not be required in the future as there's [speculation that this scenario could be a bug in Umbraco 7.4.2](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/76443-cannot-addmodelerror-during-httppost-in-surfacecontroller#comment-244458).